# Dialogflow - External JWT Token Handling

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-5.5, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I have a Laravel app that generates JWT token after login.  JWT token is required for handling all other API calls.  I am going to be using account linking feature for my dialog flow app that will require me to make API calls these JWT protected APIs.  Is there a way form to store the token in Dialogflow.  I will wiling using both Voice and Text interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google (and thus Dialogflow) only supports account linking [via OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking), not JWTs. You would have to implement OAuth in your backend service.